# MetaMask issues

Tags: metamask

I am using the latest version of Chrome and I re-installed MetaMask but the below problems persist.

1. When I enter my password into MetaMask I get the message "Network request failed".  I close MetaMask and then re-open it, and I am now successfully logged in.
2. When I try to add an ERC20 token I go through the process successfully but then the wallet just says "Loading Tokens".   All I can see is the ETH wallet.

Note: I have not added any ETH to this wallet.

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: yes thank you so much that just made my day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the cause.  I had the setting "This can read and change site data" at "When you click the extension".  Changing it back to the default setting "On all sites" resolved the above 2 issues.

Note: I was advised to select "When you click the extension" to protect my privacy.